# How to fetch latest two records based on timestamp in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, greatest-n-per-group

I have these record in table i want to fetch latest two record from this table( which is first 4 rows) using the timestamp

```
44121993    GEO     21-NOV-19 02.16.55.496000000 PM
44121993    PRODCT  21-NOV-19 02.16.55.496000000 PM
44121993    GEO     21-NOV-19 02.16.55.495000000 PM
44121993    PRODCT  21-NOV-19 02.16.55.495000000 PM
44121993    GEO     21-NOV-19 02.16.55.494000000 PM
44121993    PRODCT  21-NOV-19 02.16.55.494000000 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

After I have seen the tag **"greatest-n-per-group"**, I would suggest using `DENSE_RANK` with `PARTITION BY` to fetch the first n records per group as following:

```
SELECT * FROM
    ( SELECT
          T.*,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(
               PARTITION BY COL1 -- COL1 IS THE FIRST COLUMN FROM YOUR EXAMPLE 
                                 -- or COLUMN ON WHICH GROUPING NEED TO BE DONE
               ORDER BY TIMESTAMP_COL DESC) RN
        FROM  YOUR_TABLE T
    )
WHERE RN <= 2
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        dense_rank() over(order by timestamp_col desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn <= 2
```